# PHP - Consistent Random Output by the Day

Tags: php, date, random

I have some content on a website which I want to randomize every day. I want to keep that random output consistent for the entire day. So that if someone is going back and forth from the page they won't get lost.

I guess the key is to find a rand function that is consistent, and that uses todays date as a salt.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Consistent Random" is my new favorite oxymoron.

Answer (score 3):

```
$random_key=md5(date('y-m-s'));
```

or

```
$random_key=sha1(date('y-m-s'));
```

Comment: Okay this is a good start. I can see that I get a consistent random string. What I want to do is apply this to an array of products to shuffle them the same way for each day. Any ideas?

Comment: would be better if you can share a simple output !

Comment: Sure sorry for being a bit ambiguous. Here is a code sample I wrote up:
`$products = array();`
`$products[] = array('image' => 'product-1.jpg', 'name' => 'product 1');`
`$products[] = array('image' => 'product-2.jpg', 'name' => 'product 2');`
`$products[] = array('image' => 'product-3.jpg', 'name' => 'product 3');`

`shuffle($products);`
`//shuffle($products, md5(date('d'))); //something like this is needed`
`foreach ($products as $product) {`
  `echo $product['image'] . '<br />';`
`}`

Comment: For some reason the code I wrote above won't go on multiple lines. Is there something i need to do to indicate the new line?

Comment: i dont think ANYONE CAN WRITE MULTILINE COMMENTS  i tried and failed too :)

Comment: ahh yes i see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/format-code-in-comments

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider might be just taking the day of the year and doing a modulas of that against the array size of your set of available "random" outputs to select what to present the user.  After all, to the user "random" is a relative term as long as the content is different from yesterday. You could randomize the values in your table of available outputs only once and then you can just index into them for each day.  The output will be fresh and new for the users each day and you can avoid the constant re-hashing for each request.

Comment: @rockacola - don't you mean $banner_id_to_display = $key % $total_banner_count ? Otherwise don't you risk exceeding the banner set size as I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use `rand()` function, you can simply manipulate with date value as @Soura suggested.

A different (and dummier) example can be:

```
$key = time() / (60*60*60); // a numeric key, increment by 1 per day.
$total_banner_count = 20;
$banner_id_to_display = $key / $total_banner_count;
```